# do type=@id values have to be explicitly typed in JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm looking into JSON-LD specifically in combination with schema.org.

one of the Json-LD examples of [schema.org/Person](https://schema.org/Person) struck me as wrong:

```
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "Person",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "addressLocality": "Seattle",
            "addressRegion": "WA",
            "postalCode": "98052",
            "streetAddress": "20341 Whitworth Institute 405 N. Whitworth"
          },
          "colleague": [
            "http://www.xyz.edu/students/alicejones.html",
            "http://www.xyz.edu/students/bobsmith.html"
          ],
          "email": "mailto:jane-doe@xyz.edu",
          "image": "janedoe.jpg",
          "jobTitle": "Professor",
          "name": "Jane Doe",
          "telephone": "(425) 123-4567",
          "url": "http://www.janedoe.com"
        }
```

What seems wrong to me is that `colleague` is defined to be of type=Person (see above link), but instead an entity reference (url/text) is supplied.

The proper way to format this seems to be supplying extra info in the `@context` like so:

```
        {
          "@context": {
                "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
                "colleague": { "@type": "@id" }
            },
          "@type": "Person",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "addressLocality": "Seattle",
            "addressRegion": "WA",
            "postalCode": "98052",
            "streetAddress": "20341 Whitworth Institute 405 N. Whitworth"
          },
          "colleague": [
            "http://www.xyz.edu/students/alicejones.html",
            "http://www.xyz.edu/students/bobsmith.html"
          ],
          "email": "mailto:jane-doe@xyz.edu",
          "image": "janedoe.jpg",
          "jobTitle": "Professor",
          "name": "Jane Doe",
          "telephone": "(425) 123-4567",
          "url": "http://www.janedoe.com"
        }
```

Is the example on schema.org (code example 1) indeed incorrect/incomplete, and is code example 2 correct?

Or in general: when referencing instead of embedding entities, is it required to make this explicit (using `@type: @id`) or, alternatively, is there some implicit notion in the spec that when a value is an URL it's considered to be a reference by @id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the example is not 100% correct. The type-coercion to `@id` is missing. I filed a bug to get this fixed: https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/929

Comment: Good to know. So to answer my own generic question: referencing entities needs to always be *explicitly* marked as such correct?

Comment: Yes, either by type-coercing the property in the context or by using an inline `@id` object